# Is Warframe slowing down my laptop?

Tags: steam, warframe

Recently I downloaded Warframe. Since then I noticed my computer was doing poorly at multitasking. For example, downloading a WoT update and opening Armor Games in the Chrome Browser. I think Warframe might be slowing down my laptop because it seemed to handle multitasking much better before. The specs of my laptop can be found [here](https://www.techradar.com/reviews/acer-nitro-5). I used Steam to install Warframe on the Data D: hard drive. I installed it here because my Acer C: SSD was getting close to full. One of my friends suggested opening Task Manager and updating the priority of Steam so it would download faster, so I did. My question is this: Is Warframe slowing down my laptop? If so is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: "*I installed it here because my Acer C: SSD was getting close to full.*" Possibly relevant: https://www.howtogeek.com/165542/why-solid-state-drives-slow-down-as-you-fill-them-up/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why that was a problem, considering I had 7.62 GB free (7% of the SSD), but since cleaning the drive, giving Acer C: 9.06 GB free, I suddenly saw the speed go way up! Thank you so much for referring me to that website. From this, I take away the idea that it's probably best if you keep about 10% of any SSD free.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that would solve your problem, so I only left it as a link, but I'm glad to see it helped.